# sql server how to combine multiple results in one row?

Tags: sql, subquery

how can I display these 3 results in 1 row? I am using the Nortwnd sample db:

```
select top 1 CompanyName from dbo.Customers
select top 1 LastName from employees
select top 1 categoryname from dbo.Categories
```

I tried Union and intersect but cant get the result.

So I would like something like:

```
CompanyName         | LastName | CategoryName
Alfreds Futterkiste | Buchanan | Beverages
```

Comment: what is the relationship between these tables?

Comment: is the result only 1 row (top 1)? if yes, then you can use comma (,) between the 3 queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
CompanyName  = (select top 1 CompanyName from dbo.Customers),
LastName = (select top 1 LastName from employees),
CategoryName = (select top 1 categoryname from dbo.Categories)
```

Comment: hey brilliant          !

Comment: looks ugly.  I prefer the AS style by Linger.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you would want such results, but the following would get you what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CompanyName,
(
  SELECT TOP 1 LastName FROM dbo.employees
) AS TopLastName,
(
  SELECT TOP 1 categoryname FROM dbo.Categories
) AS TopCategory
FROM dbo.Customers
```